# C# call function when form is loaded

Tags: c#, forms

I want my program to execute a specific function everytime the form is run.
The function would be to get the baseAdress of a process, so it should be called everytime the person loads the program.
Current code:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Adicionar());
    if (getmodule()) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(baseAdress);
    }
}
static bool getmodule(){ .... }
```

how would that be possible to make? I thought maybe using it in the Form constructor? But I'm not sure how to do that.

And Also 
would this code

```
d.Adress = (0x6C7FC + baseAdress + 0xA82020);
```

return a valid value that I could write(to memory) /read?

Comment: `Adicionar_Load()` Is what you're looking for I believe, in the editor click on it and look at the events, that should be one

Comment: What you mean when say when form is run? You mean when form is created?

Comment: Do you want this to run when each time the *form is created*, or once when the *program is run*?  Those are two very different things, and you're not really clarifying between them.

Comment: Everytime the person executes the .exe

Comment: My whole program is just ONE form so I would the function to be called everytime the person executes the .exe a.k.a the form shows up